# Some conflicts were found in the installation area, while updating android studio 2022.1.1 patch 1

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-electric-eel

[image: 1]

I am getting this error while updating Android Studio 2022.1.1 patch 1 some patch gets downloaded and following error comes,

Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied.

the files that is shown are:

jre/

jre/bin/

jre/bin/.marker

Comment: Lets start with obvious. 
Do you have Java JRE installed?
Are you sure this patch is for your OS? 
Are you using widows/Linux MacOS?
Is your jre directory in your PATH variable?

Answer (score 2):

Same error. I fixed it by simply creating the missing folders and the file .marker:

In an admin terminal on Windows, simply do:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

mkdir jre
cd jre & mkdir bin
cd bin & type nul > .marker
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error.

Also to mention, because I don't know if that does matter, when I updated to electric eel, i hat to make a link by `mklink /j jre jbr` because it seems like they changed the folder name from jbr to jre. Many other solutions on stack overflow recommended to just create a jre folder and copy all the jbr stuff in it.
I was thinking that it is a temporary mistake and they will rename it with future updates back to jbr. That's why I kept the jbr folder and just linked to it with the jre link.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Just like the text said, I downloaded the new version from web and reinstalled Android Studio. Now it created by it self a `jre` folder that contained a `bin` folder that contained a `.marker` file.
The new installation by it self didn't work. Flutter doctor showed my some issues like that the android licences are not accepted and that it can't find java.
I manually copied the contend from the jbr to the jre folder, but also made sure that the `.marker` file stayed in the `jre/bin` folder.

Now everything seems to work again.