# Cannot install Patch 1 on Android Studio 2022.1.1 on Windows (because of symlink?)

Tags: android-studio, symlink, jetbrains-toolbox

I'm trying to update Android Studio 2022.1.1 to Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 1 on Windows 11 Home edition. I did the same on a Linux partition and it worked.

The patch is downloaded and a restart is required. When I restart the IDE, though, the update fails with this error message:

[image]

> An error occurred when preparing the patch:
> java.io.IOException: An absolute link: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre -> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

The log file reads:

```
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Runner.initLogger - --- Updater started ---
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Runner._main - args: [install, C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio]
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Runner._main - destination: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio), case-sensitive: false
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Utils.getTempFile - created a working directory: C:\Users\vanet\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\tmp\patch-update\idea.updater.files.2070024887130819060
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Runner.install - Extracting patch file...
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Utils.getZipEntry - entryPath: patch-file.zip
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Utils.getZipEntry - entryPath: .patch-info
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate - Android Studio 221.6008.13.2211.9477386 -> 221.6008.13.2211.9514443
20/02 14:57:18 INFO  Patch.forEach - Validating installation... [3175 actions]
20/02 14:57:18 ERROR Runner.install - prepare failed
java.io.IOException: An absolute link: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre -> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:50)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:450)
    at com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.validate(DeleteAction.java:42)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$validate$0(Patch.java:292)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:438)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:291)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate(PatchFileCreator.java:109)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:413)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner._main(Runner.java:221)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:49)

20/02 14:57:34 INFO  Runner.cleanup - Cleaning up...
20/02 14:57:34 INFO  Utils.tryDelete - deleted: C:\Users\vanet\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\tmp\patch-update\idea.updater.files.2070024887130819060\patch.tmp.0
20/02 14:57:34 INFO  Utils.tryDelete - deleted: C:\Users\vanet\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\tmp\patch-update\idea.updater.files.2070024887130819060
20/02 14:57:34 INFO  Utils.cleanup - deleted a working directory: C:\Users\vanet\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\tmp\patch-update\idea.updater.files.2070024887130819060
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Runner.initLogger - --- Updater started ---
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Runner._main - args: [install, C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio]
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Runner._main - destination: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio), case-sensitive: false
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Utils.getTempFile - created a working directory: C:\Users\vanet\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\tmp\patch-update\idea.updater.files.11969764392612736673
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Runner.install - Extracting patch file...
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Utils.getZipEntry - entryPath: patch-file.zip
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Utils.getZipEntry - entryPath: .patch-info
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate - Android Studio 221.6008.13.2211.9477386 -> 221.6008.13.2211.9514443
20/02 14:58:53 INFO  Patch.forEach - Validating installation... [3175 actions]
20/02 14:58:53 ERROR Runner.install - prepare failed
java.io.IOException: An absolute link: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre -> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:50)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:450)
    at com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.validate(DeleteAction.java:42)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$validate$0(Patch.java:292)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:438)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:291)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate(PatchFileCreator.java:109)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:413)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner._main(Runner.java:221)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:49)
```

The `jre` directory is a symbolic link to the `jbr` (JetBrains) directory that contains the Java Runtime Environment.

What's the issue here?

It should have something to do with the same problem that caused [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345070/some-conflicts-were-found-in-the-installation-area-while-updating-android-studi), but I'd like to understand the issue instead of just finding a provisional workaround.

Comment: Same here. I'm on Linux. Trying to apply patch 2 for android-studio-2022.1.1.

Comment: For me on Linux, simply removing the absolute link and retrying helped: `:> rm /opt/android-studio-2022.1.1/android-studio/jre`

Comment: This last comment from @krevelen worked for me, even upgrading to Iguana.